# XSLT template concatenating string / how to stop

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSLT stylesheet that is concatenating a template variable. I cannot figure out how to stop it from doing this but also keeping the single variable.
I have pasted the code and the transformation below... You can see the `Startdt` variable value `02/01/2017` is concatenated to repeat three times.

***Code***

```
 <xsl:variable name="VPlan" select="wd:DEP_VISION_planname/wd:ID[@wd:type = 'Health_Care_Coverage_Plan_ID']"/>
        <xsl:variable name="MPlan" select="wd:DEPMEDPLAN/wd:ID[@wd:type = 'Health_Care_Coverage_Plan_ID']"/>
        <xsl:variable name="DPlan" select="wd:DEPDENT_PLAN/wd:ID[@wd:type = 'Health_Care_Coverage_Plan_ID']"/>

        <xsl:if test="$VPlan = 'HEALTH_CARE_COVERAGE_PLAN-Vision - United Health Care'">
             <xsl:call-template name="Depplan">
                <xsl:with-param name="Deplan" select="'UHC Vision'"/>
                 <xsl:with-param name="Startdt" select="../wd:COBRA_Records_within_Range/wd:COBRA_Eligible_Date"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="$DPlan = 'HEALTH_CARE_COVERAGE_PLAN-Dental - MetLife Enhanced'">
            <xsl:call-template name="Depplan">
                <xsl:with-param name="Deplan" select="'Metlife Dental ASO Enhanced'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="Startdt" select="../wd:COBRA_Records_within_Range/wd:COBRA_Eligible_Date"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="$DPlan = 'HEALTH_CARE_COVERAGE_PLAN-Dental - MetLife Basic'">
            <xsl:call-template name="Depplan">
                <xsl:with-param name="Deplan" select="'Metlife Dental ASO Basic'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="Startdt" select="../wd:COBRA_Records_within_Range/wd:COBRA_Eligible_Date"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="$MPlan = 'HEALTH_CARE_COVERAGE_PLAN-Medical - Medical Mutual of Ohio PPO SuperMed Plus'">
            <xsl:call-template name="Depplan">
                <xsl:with-param name="Deplan" select="'Medical Mutual Medical MMO PPO'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="Startdt" select="../wd:COBRA_Records_within_Range/wd:COBRA_Eligible_Date"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="$MPlan = 'HEALTH_CARE_COVERAGE_PLAN-Medical - AETNA PPO Network/Non Network'">
            <xsl:call-template name="Depplan">
                <xsl:with-param name="Deplan" select="'Aetna Medical PPO'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="Startdt" select="../wd:COBRA_Records_within_Range/wd:COBRA_Eligible_Date"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="$MPlan = 'HEALTH_CARE_COVERAGE_PLAN-Medical - HealthSpan HMO Network Only'">
            <xsl:call-template name="Depplan">
                <xsl:with-param name="Deplan" select="'HealthSpan Medical HMO'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="Startdt" select="../wd:COBRA_Records_within_Range/wd:COBRA_Eligible_Date"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>  

        <xsl:template name="Depplan">
            <xsl:param name="Deplan"/>
            <xsl:param name="Startdt"/>

            <xsl:text>[QBDEPENDENTPLAN]</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="insertDelimiter"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Deplan"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="insertDelimiter"/>
           <!-- <xsl:call-template name="FormatDateValue">
                <xsl:with-param name="dateString">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Startdt"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template> -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$Startdt"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="insertDelimiter"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="insertDelimiter"/>
            <xsl:text>T</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="insertNewLine"/>
        </xsl:template>
```

***Output***

> [QBDEPENDENTPLAN],UHC Vision,02/01/2017 02/01/2017 02/01/2017,,T
>   [QBDEPENDENTPLAN],Metlife Dental ASO Enhanced,02/01/2017 02/01/2017 02/01/2017,,T
>   [QBDEPENDENTPLAN],Aetna Medical PPO,02/01/2017 02/01/2017 02/01/2017,,T

Answer (score 0):

The date printed 3 times is a result of `<xsl:value-of select="$Startdt"/>` command.

Its value comes from

`<xsl:with-param name="Startdt" select="../wd:COBRA_Records_within_Range/wd:COBRA_Eligible_Date"/>`

I suppose that the XPath use here (`../wd:COBRA_Records_within_Range/wd:COBRA_Eligible_Date`):

- has found 3 records (from `wd:COBRA_Records_within_Range`),
- prints date (`wd:COBRA_Eligible_Date`) from **each** record.

One of possible solutions is to print the date only from the 1st record found:

```
../wd:COBRA_Records_within_Range[1]/wd:COBRA_Eligible_Date
```

If you can guarantee that all these dates (from all records) are the same, no further considerations are needed.

But what if these dates were different?
You must consider this on your own.

Comment: Thanks this worked. I am pretty sure the dates for each that are in range should  be the same.